# Client successHandler gets null, but server logs show results

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I am trying to list all editors of a Google Spreadsheet in an HTML iframe inside a Google Sheet sidebar. As you can see in the code below, I show the results in the Logger; it works there, shows me the list of editors. But when I pass the results to the HTML file using `google.script.run`, it seems to "get lost" on the way. I receive no errors, just a 'null' list in the sidebar.

I have the following code in the .gs:

```
function myFunction() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form1');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function editores() {
  var editors = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getEditors();
  for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
    var editor = editors[i];
    Logger.log(editor)
    }
  return editors;    
}
```

And this code in the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
    function listEditors(editors) {
      for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
        var eltag = document.getElementById('edit').innerHTML;
        var edit = editors[i];
        document.getElementById('edit').innerHTML = eltag+'<br/>'+edit;
      }
    }

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(listEditors).editores();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p id='edit'></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I execute `myFunction()` it opens the sidebar showing a list of "null". But when I open the Logger in the script console it shows the list of editors fine... Seems like the data is "lost" on the way through.

Comment: for some reason getEditors does not work for me right now but apart from that your code is working perfectly well, Do you see any error in the javascript console ?

Comment: no errors, just a 'null' list in the sidebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing an array of Google Apps Script [User objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user), and since only simple objects can be returned to the client<sup>*</sup>, the result is `null`.

One way to fix this is to use [`getEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getEmail()) to get each user's address as a string, and return an array of those:

```js
function editores() {
  var editors = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getEditors();
  var editorStrArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < editors.length; i++) {
    var editor = editors[i];
    Logger.log(editor);
    editorStrArray.push(editor.getEmail())
  }
  return editorStrArray;    
}
```

---

<sup>*</sup>The docs for `google.script.run` say that the rules for return values (to successHandlers) are the same as for parameters to server-side functions, specifically:

> Legal parameters are JavaScript primitives like a Number, Boolean, String, or null, as well as JavaScript objects and arrays that are composed of primitives, objects, and arrays.